# Correct usage of comma- Specific sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas

1. I don't have a choice but to reply since I try my best to dispel hate, which you're proficient at.

I wanted to know if the use of a comma is appropriate in the above sentence? What does the sentence mean? Is the person proficient at dispelling hatred or is he hateful himself?

2. I found the text online and wanted to know if the text is legitimate.

Will there be a comma before 'and' in the above statement?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Please include the research that you have done - see our [tour] for more details.

Comment: In relation to example 2, your phrase  "I found the text online and wanted to know if the text is legitimate" is perfect.  No comma is required.

Answer (score 2):

The comma is placed appropriately in example 1. The clause "I try my best to dispel hate" is obviously modified by the which (relative) clause that follows it.

However, note that the *which* clause is a non-restrictive clause and also a modifier. As a conventional rule, modifiers certainly need to be very close to the ideas they modify, which is properly done in example 1. As in your first example, the *which* (relative) clause is placed correctly, modifying the clause that precedes it.  Since it is non-restrictive (non-essential to the sentence's meaning), it is set apart from the clause it modifies by the comma.

The sentence could stand alone without the relative clause, but what the relative clause does here is to add supplementary information to the antecedent action, telling us the relationship between what he isn't good at and what the other person is good at.

The example 1, as written, means he doesn't have a choice and tried to dispel hate--which he isn't good at--while acknowledging the other person's proficiency in dispelling hate.

Comment: Re your first question, @Demilade has given an excellent answer about whether a comma is necessary.

Re your second question "Is the person proficient at dispelling hatred or is he hateful himself?", the "I" refers to the author and the "you" to the recipient. Hence the sentence means:

"I (the author) try to **dispel** hate, but you (the recipient of this message) are proficient at **creating** hate."